# Order BY Customized - Char by Char

Tags: sqlite, order-by

My target is to sort text columns by a custom sorting.
e.g., `ADBC` instead of the usual `ABCD`.

With this custom ordering, rows would be *ordered by* in this way:

```
ADAGIO
ABACUS
DICE
BEE
```

Because D comes before B.

If I'd need to sort texts of one letter that would be easy:

```
SELECT * FROM my_db
ORDER BY case when text_plain = 'A' then 1
              when text_plain = 'D' then 2
              when text_plain = 'B' then 3
              when text_plain = 'C' then 4
              else 5
         end asc
```

But text contains multiple characters.
Is this feasible?

I am using Sqlite in this case.

Comment: Which language are you using to access SQLite?

Comment: I'm using SQL language, I'm using SQLiteStudio client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's C API has functions to create [custom collations](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html).

SQLiteStudio allows you to [create such collations](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/User_Manual#custom-collations) in any of its supported scripting languages.

Comment: That's it thank you. I saw there is an sql buil-in script language plugin, not clear yet what is the syntax, the documentation is quite short, I'll keep looking around.